# Invalid argument supplied for foreach while fetching data from the model

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter. I am getting an error

```
Message: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.
```

Let's explain you in details.
Below is the code which I am using in the controller

```
  $send->customer_id=1;//This is just for information

  $fetchdata=$this->Member_model->getAll($send->customer_id);
```

I got an output. I found `two` records which are related to the `1`

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 825
            [customer_id] => 123
            [profile_pic] => sbc.jpg
            [first_name] => Shagun
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [member_id] => 
            [customer_id] => 
            [profile_pic] => abfg.jpg
            [first_name] => Mayra 
        )

)
```

Just notice that I am not getting the `member_id` and `customer_id` in the second array.

Below is the model code which I am getting my output

**Model**

```
public function getAll($id){
    $get_s_member = array('members.is_Approved'=>1,'relation_member.primary_customer_id' =>$id);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('members'); 
        $this->db->join('relation_member', 'relation_member.secondary_member_id = members.member_id','LEFT');
        $this->db->join('relations', 'relations.relations_id = relation_member.relation_with_primary_member','LEFT'); 
        $this->db->join('membership_details', 'members.member_id = membership_details.member_id','LEFT'); 
        $this->db->where($get_s_member);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $res   = $query->result();
     return $res;
  }
```

Why I am getting the empty because there is no record in the `membership_details` table. I need at least members table should display there all the record.

I have to pass the member_id here

```
$allData['allActivitys']=$this->Member_model->getActivity($member_id);

foreach ($allData['allActivitys'] as $key => $sec_activities) {

}
```

Model

```
public function getActivity($gotSecondaryMemberId){
        $getDetails = array('members.member_id'=>$gotSecondaryMemberId);
$result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
                ->select('*')
                ->from('members')
                ->join('relation_member', 'relation_member.secondary_member_id = members.member_id')
                ->join('relations', 'relations.relations_id = relation_member.relation_with_primary_member')
                ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id','LEFT')
                ->join('activity_name', 'activity_name.activity_name_id = member_activity.activity_id','LEFT')
                ->get()
                ->result();

    if($result)
    {
         return $result;  
    }
    else 
    {
       return 0;  
    }

  }
```

but it's getting only first array and in the secondary error it's error Message: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Comment: where is getActivity() ????

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, ok, I will update it in the question within 5 min

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, I updated getActivity() code in the question.

Comment: return blank array instead of 0 on else. `if($result)
    {
         return $result;  
    }
    else 
    {
       return [];  
    }`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, can you explain me little bit more

Comment: either you need to check array before it pass to foreach same as Bhavin's answer, or you can pass blank array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188109/discussion-between-devsi-odedra-and-user9437856).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to just add some `if` conditions before `foreach` loop

```
$allData['allActivitys']=$this->Member_model->getActivity($member_id);
if(!empty($allData) && isset($allData['allActivitys'] )){
    foreach ($allData['allActivitys'] as $key => $sec_activities) {
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: yes, it's working perfectly. Can you explain to me a little bit?

Comment: Hi, if it works you can accept my answer @user9437856

Comment: First of all it is checking if value available in array and then checking our array key is there or not.

Comment: ok..  if there are no records in the right table then it will display the at least left table records?

Comment: @user9437856 then you have to use `leftJoin` instead of `join`